# Allow users to enable keyboard shortcuts across all network sites at once

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, keyboard-shortcuts, preferences

I've just got into keyboard shortcuts, and I found it a bit annoying that for every network site I use (Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault, etc.) I have to go to `http://<site>.com/users/preferences/<UID>` and set it on.

There are some preferences which should be per-site on that same page, e.g. the newsletter. But I think most people will want shortcut uniformity like me.

Comment: This is actually *already* available for updating your profile (except that "canceling" after hitting "apply to all" didn't work for me) so, yes, you have my vote.

Answer (score 0):

This has [finally been implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312501/145951) along with a couple other global preferences.

I think this post should be tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).